Can I make a container fit its transform-scaled element
Let's say I have a container which contains a label which is transformed using scale. Container doesn't match the dimensions of the label and it has width/height of pre-transformed label. I want to make container match the size of its nested scaled element without using JS.
So here's a very simplified snippet of what I'm trying to achieve:


.x {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}

.y {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
}
<div class='root'>
<div class='x'>
<div class='y'>
label
</div>
</div>
</div>



In this example, x is bigger than y and matches its y pre-transformed size, but if you hover y in the web inspector it shows its true size which x doesn't inherit.
Here's what should be getting instead:

Honestly I need only width to match and I was trying to do stuff like width: calc(100% - 20px) but that didn't work.

Without JS, you can't. A transform is purely visual, it has no effect on layout or actual sizing.

@Paulie_D I guess that makes sense, thank you. This was some legacy code that I was trying to make modifications to but instead of doing that I've tried different approach. For reference that was input which had it label animated using scale when focused. Instead of doing that I just animated font-size property and got rid off transform completely.

The most simple way here is to apply scale on .x not .y

The answer is no. Element is transformed at screen, but remains the same in the flow.  Position:relative and offset coordonates does the same.

See - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Dobxgm
